# How can I stop a for each loop iteration if I need to call break inside a switch in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

How to stop for each loop? On return error message next loop should not run, stop the for each loop. So, it will handle sequentially error shown:

```
if let fields = data.keys ?? [] {
    for each in fields {
        switch each.key {
            case One:
              let errorOne =  errorValidation(id: each.id,name:each.name, keyValue: each.key)
                if errorOne.count > 0 {
                    // Stop For Each
                }
            case Two:
                let errorTwo =  errorValidation(id: each.id,name:each.name, keyValue: each.key)
                if errorTwo.count > 0 {
                    // Stop For Each
                }
            case Three:
                let errorThree =  errorValidation(id: each.id,name:each.name, keyValue: each.key)
                if errorThree.count > 0 {
                    // Stop For Each
                }
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
func errorValidation(id: String, name: String, keyValue: String) -> String {
    var errorMessage = String()
    switch keyValue {
        case One:
            if name.isEmpty {
                errorMessage = "One Is Empty"
            }
        case Two:
            if name.isEmpty {
                errorMessage = "Two Is Empty"
            }
        case Three:
            if name.isEmpty {
                errorMessage = "Three Is Empty"
            }
        default: break
    }
    return errorMessage
    printVMSLog("Error \(errorMessage)") // Always Print Three IS Empty
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [labeled statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html). You can name your loop and then you can specify which loop you would like to break:

```
if let fields = data.keys ?? []{
    fieldsLoop: for each in fields {
        switch each.key {
            case One:
              let errorOne =  errorValidation(id: each.id,name:each.name, keyValue: each.key)
                if errorOne.count > 0 {
                    break fieldsLoop
                }
            case Two:
                let errorTwo =  errorValidation(id: each.id,name:each.name, keyValue: each.key)
                if errorTwo.count > 0 {
                    break fieldsLoop
                }
            case Three:
                let errorThree =  errorValidation(id: each.id,name:each.name, keyValue: each.key)
                if errorThree.count > 0 {
                    break fieldsLoop
                }
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know there is concept call Labeled Statement.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to skip the`switch` and do

```
if let fields = data.keys ?? [] {
    for each in fields {
        if [One, Two, Three].contains(each.key) {
            let error = errorValidation(id: each.id,name:each.name, keyValue: each.key)
            if !error.isEmpty {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```